# In Firebase, can I trigger a conversion only if an event has a certain parameter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a Firebase Event called `conversion_performed`.  It has a parameter `success`.

Can I trigger a conversion only if the parameter `success` is `"true"`?  Or do I need to have two different events:  `conversion_succeeded` and `conversion_failed`?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events
Would like to know if handling conversion inside single event is not suitable for your problem?

Comment: @vinoth10 It is not.  I only want to trigger the conversion depending on the value of the paramters.

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading some documentation, Google Analytics for Firebase provides event reports that help you understand how users interact with your app. You can create custom tag in order to track the user behavior and create custom analytics trigger to allow a proper process related to this event.

In special, there are a king of tags called *conversions*, based in [this definition](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086209?hl=en) the conversions are classified in macro and micro.And I think, this classification is important for your question.

In case of macro conversion, if your trigger processes a large amount of information and perform multiple operations over a single *event/conversion*, I think you should separate in both *tags* to isolate each processing. Or if you require to perform very different path of data process based on success, I strongly suggest separate the event in two.

On the other hand, in case of micro conversion, if the processing trigger does not have much work and if the knowledge of the success of the conversion is part of a unique processing path, I suggest keep just one conversion trigger.

In a nutshell, your questions depends entirely about your problem nature. And I suggest two criteria to separarte or not your conversion trigger.

- Heavy process - Separate your tags in app/web or create several pub/sub trigger to separate processing.
- Isolated behavior - If the execution of the trigger is totally different depending on the success of the *conversion*, I recommend two *conversions* and two triggers.

I have completely changed the answer to try to go deeper into your problem because I think, the first one was very shallow. And I hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand the first approach. How would it trigger a conversation?